# I want to insert link into my images which come from database and fetch to their related data using asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

In my SQL Server I wrote a stored procedure which take `BrandName` and searches it and returns related records. It work properly.

But in view were I make images and insert link on it and when click on the image it sent its name and other side it used for search in my code only last image tag worked properly, when I click other images then it give error DBNull error...

View

```
@model IEnumerable<BusinessLayer.Entities.ProductDetail>

<div class="row">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Manufacture","home",new {BrandName=item.BrandName})"><img src="~/Images/Brands/@item.BrandImage" width="100" height="100" /> </a>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

In repository

```
public IEnumerable<ProductDetail> BrandData(string BrandName) 
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("searchinthebaseofBrand", DACUtil.getConnection());
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BrandName", BrandName);

    List<ProductDetail> pd = null;

    using (SqlConnection con = cmd.Connection) 
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (sdr.HasRows)
        {
            pd = new List<ProductDetail>();

            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                ProductDetail pro = new ProductDetail()
                        {
                            ProductDetail_Id = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["ProductDetail_Id"]),
                             ProductName = Convert.ToString(sdr["ProductName"]),
                            ProductDescription = Convert.ToString(sdr["ProductDescription"]),
                        };
                pd.Add(pro);
            }

            pd.TrimExcess();
        }
    }

    return pd;
}
```

In controller

```
public ActionResult Manufacture(string BrandName)
        {
            if (BrandName == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(context1.BrandData(BrandName));
        }
```

When I click other images not last one it give me following error:

[image: InvalidCastException Error window]

Comment: Url to image is not working. Maybe copy paste the error into your text?

Comment: The image you showed does not include the stack trace. Can you give us that information?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your method is not filling in the BrandImage or the BrandName property so it is defaulting to null

```
    ProductDetail pro = new ProductDetail()
                            {
                                ProductDetail_Id = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["ProductDetail_Id"]),
                                 ProductName = Convert.ToString(sdr["ProductName"]),
                                ProductDescription = Convert.ToString(sdr["ProductDescription"]),
BrandImage =  = Convert.ToString(sdr["BrandImage"]),
BrandName =  = Convert.ToString(sdr["BrandName"]),
                        };
```